# Map does not show up in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I spent time working on a project, and I saved it.

I'm sure now when I open it again .. ArcMap does not display my map ..the layers there and everything else but the  map's not displaying.

It happened to me more than one time I don't know why.

My map is so big so could that be the reason?

Answer (score 3):

Are you saving it on one computer and opening it on another?  If that's the case, you will want to look at setting [relative paths](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00660000000w000000).  If your layers have red exclamation points next to them, it means it cannot locate the source data, and you will have to manually [point to the source](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//006m0000006q000000.htm)

Another thought is that if you are using a served basemap, it might be causing some drawing issues.  Try disabling any basemaps you have loaded.

Apart from these suggestions, adding a screenshot of what you are experiencing, and some more information on what types of data you have in your map, etc. might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

I found your question because I had a similar problem. I could see my map file in both Layout and Data view, but the map just wouldn't display when I checked its box.
Eventually I noticed that I was using the 'List by Source' tab in the Table of Contents. When I changed to 'List by Drawing Order' I was able to select the map's group and it displayed again. So simple, yet so frustrating :)